# Why gradle android plugin doesn't generate dependencies for intellij idea module

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, gradle

I have gradle project with 4 subprojects and I 'm using idea plugin to generate idea project and modules. 
One of the subprojects is android module.

Here is it's build.gradle code:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {

    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"
    compileSdkVersion 16

    sourceSets {

        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aild.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile(
            ['org.atmosphere:wasync:1.1.0'],
            ['org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-lgpl:1.9.13'],
            ['org.projectlombok:lombok:0.+'],
            ['org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.1'],
            ['commons-io:commons-io:2.+'],
            ['com.google.guava:guava:14.+']
    )
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

The problem is: when using "gradle idea" to generate intellij idea modules, resulting android module is missing dependencies and I can't figure out why. 
Is something wrong with my config?

Other subprojects (using java plugin) have dependencies imported in idea modules without problems.

I am using gradle 1.7.

Answer (score 3):

Importing gradle project in Idea solved the problem of dependencies not being imported for android module, but caused a bunch of more (and worse) problems described in this question:
[IntelliJ, Android and Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133414/intellij-android-and-gradle)

Comment: Also, it seems that when one of subprojects is android gradle project, IDEA treats whole project as android project (it looks for local.properties in project root, ads AndroidGradle facets to all modules)

Answer (score 0):

Idea plugin can process `compile` configuration of java plugin, but not android plugin (for now). But this can be solved by hand, place it near your `android {}` and `apply plugin:` blocks:

```
beforeEvaluate {
    idea.module.scopes.put("COMPILE", ["plus": [], "minus": []])
    idea.module.scopes.COMPILE.plus += configurations.compile
    idea.module.sourceDirs += file('src')
}
```

First line is related to inner details of idea plugin, second actually addes dependencies declared under `compile` configuration inside `dependencies` closure. Third is not related to the question but adds src folder to Idea's sources.